# After he became manager, people were suddenly falling over themselves to help him

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

> After he became manager, people were suddenly falling over themselves to help him.

What's the literal meaning of 'fall over oneself'?

Comment: They were literally *tripping over each other* in the mad rush to get somewhere and do something. As per [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=falling+over+themselves+to+help+%2Cfalling+over+himself+to+help+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), we're not so likely to use this idiomatic expression with a ***singular*** subject, because it's easier to imagine tripping over *someone else's* feet than your own. But *falling over himself [to do something]* does occur.

Answer (score 0):

here is the meaning= to be very eager to do something, especially something you do not usually do:
People were falling over themselves to help her.

Comment: I asked the literal meaning not the intended meaning.